# How to write a structure in kernel space to a file in user space using kernel module?

Tags: module, kernel

```
struct stud
{
 char name[10];
 int rno;
}s[10];
```

I want to send the data of structure array s from a kernel module to a file in userspace. One way is to combine the data to form a string and send through copy_to_user() but it'll further require tokenization to separate out the data in userspace.

Plz suggest some effective method.

Answer (score 0):

@Gaurav, go through the below link and decide upon which mechanism to use to transfer data from kernel space to user space or vice-versa.

http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/kernel_user_space_howto.html

Hope link helps to solve your problem!.